# Mat-table cell binding alias

Tags: angular, mat-table

I am trying to enable sorting on a `mat-table`, and I understood that `*matColumnDef` and the binding element must have the same name.  
In my case I need to call a getter on the element.

How can I handle this? Can I define an alias?

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> NAME </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let person"> {{person.getName()}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Could I alias `person.getName()` to `name` somewhere so it will match `matColumnDef` ?

**EDIT:**

I tried something like bellow, but it doesn't work:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> NAME </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let person; let name = person.getName()"> {{name}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you maybe create stackblitz with the problem you're going to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tell you that, but things are gonna get a bit more complicated from now on.

As you've set a custom field, you'll have to explain to angular how to access the real "data" to sort on.

Here is a code sample:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

constructor() {
   this.datasource = new MatTableDataSource();
}


ngOnInit() {
  this.datasource.sort = this.sort;

  this.datasource.sortingDataAccessor = (person: Person, field: string) => {
    switch (field) {
      case 'name': return person.getName();
      default: throw new Error('Unknown field used for sorting: ' + field);
    }
  };
}
```

You should take a look at the documentation => https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good, but I have some another issue that is stopping me to get to the point of testing `sortingDataAccessor`. I raised another question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050538/angular-mat-table-custom-data-source-undefined-matsort