# Angular mat-table custom data source undefined MatSort

Tags: angular, sorting, mat-table

I have a mat-table with a custom data source (that implements `DataSource` and returns an `observable` on `connect`), similar to [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/). 
I enabled the search, but my `@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;` is still undefined.
I do not have any `*ngIf` and I also gave some initial data to my custom `dataSource` just to test some of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786757/angular-matsort-not-working), but it still does not work:

```js
export class ItemsDataSource implements DataSource<Item>{
    private dummyItem: Item = {};

    private items: Item[] = [this.dummyItem];
    private subject = new BehaviorSubject<Item[]>(this.items);
    readonly items$ = this.subject.asObservable();

    constructor() { 
      this.dummyItem.setName(`first`);
      this.subject.next(this.items);    // Have some initial data
    }

    connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Item[]> {
      return this.items$;
    }

    disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
      this.subject.complete();
    }

    // This is used by the items service to add streamed items when they become available 
    public add(item: Item) {
      this.items.push(item);
      this.subject.next(this.items);
    }
  }
```

```js
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    readonly displayedColumns: string[] = ['name'];
    public dataSource: ItemsDataSource;

    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) set matSort(sort: MatSort) {
      // `sort` is undefined here
      // sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => console.log(`sorting`));
    } 

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private scanService: ItemsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.pipe(map(param => param.name)).subscribe(name => {

        // The scan service will create the ItemsDataSource the first time it is requested
        this.dataSource = this.scanService.dataSource(name);

        // `this.sort` is undefined here
        // this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => console.log(`sorting`));
      });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      // `this.sort` is undefined here
      //this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => console.log(`sorting`));
    }
  }
```

```html
<table id="items" mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z2">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef> NAME </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.getName()}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I am kind of stuck, any ideas?

Comment: Does your table is displayed with data?

Comment: Yes, it get's displayed with the initial `dummyItem` that I pass to the `subject` in the constructor of the `ItemsDataSource`

Comment: added MatSortModule to the project?

Comment: The scan service will create the `ItemsDataSource` the first time it is requested. I added a comment also in the question code, above the place where this happens.

Comment: Yes, `MatSortModule` is added. Otherwise I was getting an error.